# How to get datetimepicker c# winform checked/unchecked event

Tags: c#, winforms, events, datetimepicker

There is a check box in the datetimepicker control of winforms .net.
But I could not find the event that is triggered when the check box is checked or unchecked .
Is there a way out?

Comment: Take a look here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/27dd3141-5dfb-439e-8e30-e051a019303a/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You´ll have to store the old "checked" value in order to compare to the new one, so you´ll be able to determine if the "checked" state has changed:

```
bool oldDateChecked = false; //if it's created as not checked

private void dtp_filtro_date_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dtp_filtro_date.Checked != oldDateChecked)
    {
        oldDateChecked = this.dtp_filtro_date.Checked;
        //do your stuff ...

    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

It does however trigger the value changed event

Answer (score 3):

Run into the same issue. I needed a CheckedChangedEvent on a winforms DateTimePicker control. So with the inspiration of the answers before me I created an inherited User Control named DateTimePicker2, inheriting from DateTimePicker that implements this event. It looks like it works but no guarantees.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public partial class DateTimePicker2 : DateTimePicker
    {
        private bool _checked;

        public new bool Checked
        {
            get
            {
                return base.Checked;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != base.Checked)
                {
                    base.Checked = value;
                    _checked = base.Checked;
                    OnCheckedChanged(new CheckedChangedEventArgs { OldCheckedValue = !value, NewCheckedValue = value });
                }
            }
        }

        public event CheckedChangedEventHandler CheckedChanged;

        public DateTimePicker2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _checked = Checked;
        }


        protected virtual void OnCheckedChanged(CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (CheckedChanged != null) CheckedChanged(this, e);
        }

        private void DateTimePicker2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Checked != _checked)
            {
                _checked = Checked;
                CheckedChangedEventArgs cce = new CheckedChangedEventArgs { OldCheckedValue = !_checked, NewCheckedValue = _checked };
                OnCheckedChanged(cce);
            }
        } 
    }

    public delegate void CheckedChangedEventHandler(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e);

    public class CheckedChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public bool OldCheckedValue { get; set; }
        public bool NewCheckedValue { get; set; }
    }

}
```

And off-course don't forget to subscribe to the DateTimePicker2_ValueChanged event from the designer.

The reason why I used both a new Checked property (to hide the base.Checked one) and a _checked field to keep truck of the old value, is because

1. the base.Checked property does not fire the ValueChanged event when changed programmatically and therefore needed a new property that could do that.
2. the this.Checked new property does not fire the ValueChanged event when changed from the UI and therefore needed a flag that would track the base.Checked property.

Basically a combination of both approaches was needed.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Good and simple solution. To make it according to fashion 2017, use `event EventHandler<CheckedChangedEventArgs>` instead of delegate. To raise the event use `this.CheckedChanged?.Invoke(this, e)` Furthermore, subscribe to the `ValueChanged` in the constructor: `this.ValueChanged += DateTimePicker_ValueChanged`. This way you are certain that no one can prevent this class from proper functioning. The new Checked is called for programmatic changes, the ValueChanged event is raised during changes made by operator.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is super old but this could help someone.

You can capture `DataTimePicker.MouseUp` event

```
private void dateTimePicker1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (((DateTimePicker)sender).Checked)
        {
            //Do whatever you need to do when the check box gets clicked
        }
        else
        {
            //Do another stuff...
        }
    }
```

You will need to do the same with `KeyUp` event in order to get the Space key press that could also activate the checkbox.