# Setting DateTimePicker.Checked property programmatically doesn't trigger .ValueChanged event

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a `DateTimePicker` which has a check box (`ShowCheckBox = True`). In my code I check and uncheck it based on various factors automatically, but allow the user to override this (hence not using `dtp.Enabled = False`).

The checked state of `dtp` also changes the `.Enabled` property of other controls, so I am trying to handle in the ValueChanged event, e.g.:

```
Private Sub dtp_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dtp.ValueChanged

    If dtp.Checked Then
        SomeOtherControl.Enabled = True
    Else
        SomeOtherControl.Enabled = False
    End If

End Sub
```

This works correctly when the user is doing the interaction, but if I programmatically set the checked state the `ValueChanged` event does not trigger.

This behaviour is noted in a comment in this question: [How to get datetimepicker c# winform checked/unchecked event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090167/how-to-get-datetimepicker-c-sharp-winform-checked-unchecked-event#comment23171683_7090255)

I can't find any other reference to this behaviour in documentation.

Is this expected, if so, why? And if not, how can I ensure changing the checked state programmatically triggers the ValueChanged event?

Comment: This is common for several Winforms controls, they do not tell you about something you did in your own code.  So you'd have to generate the event yourself, consider to derive your own class from DateTimePicker and add a CheckChanged event.

Comment: Thanks, it seems really inconsistent but if that's the way it is... The joy of WinForms! I'll implement a CheckChanged event.

Comment: When you set the checked status in code, trigger the event yourself: `dtp.Checked = Not dtp.Checked dtp.BeginInvoke(New Action(Sub() dtp_ValueChanged(dtp, Nothing)))`

Comment: Thanks Jimi, that's a useful trick.

Comment: Not exactly a trick. Another way is to simply use a method that will be called by all setters. Make a `ChangeValue(checked as Boolean)` Sub, where you have `SomeOtherControl.Enabled = checked`. Call it from `dtp_ValueChanged` passing `dtp.Checked` as argument and when you change, in code, the `Checked` status of your DTP.

Comment: Haha, I meant trick more in the old sense of the word: "a clever or particular way of doing something.".Thanks for the other suggestion as well.